# Excel export from ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, mvvm, itemscontrol

Since I am very new to WPF and **MVVM pattern** I have difficulties concerning a task.

**The task is about exporting to MS Excel the data that is shown in ItemsControl.** But with being loyal to the design it is a bit hard.

Do you have any suggestions on how to find a better way understanding these things?

For instance the `ItemsControl` is inside a `TabItem`. There are two tabitems. The data changes depending on the `SelectedIndex` of the `TabControl`. What must I do to change the data depending on the `selectedindex` of the `tab`. Because when I click the "Export to Excel" button I need to verify that I have the right data.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In the View Model you might have a collection of items that is binded to the `ItemSource` property of your `ItemsControl`. If this is the case, you can easily parse the collection in View Model and export to Excel whatever information you want.

```
List<CustomClass> items = new List<CustomClass>();
//TODO: populate items
foreach (CustomClass item in items)
{
    //TODO: do something with the item
}
```

I hope I got your problem right.

Comment: If you post a more specific task I can provide you a more specific piece of code